# Pytorch logical indexing in a 3D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime, tensor, logical-operators

I have three tensors, `a` with size(n,4,m), `b` with size(n,4,1), `c` with size (n,k,m). `a` contains batch of node features I want to get, `b` indicates valid node index (invalid index is masked by 999), `c` is the batch of node feature set to be exact. **n** and **k** are for number of batch and number of nodes respectively.

The goal is to replace valid node features of `a` with corresponding node features of `c` with the index value sorted in `b`

So far, I use a nested **for** loop to implement it

```
import torch
n=4
a = torch.arange(n*4*4).view(n,4,4)
value_c = torch.zeros(n,6,4)
b=torch.randint(0,3,(n,4,1))
b[0,1:]=999
b[2,2:] = 999
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(4):
        if b[i,j]<999:
            a[i,j]=value_c[i,b[i,j].long()]
```

But it is really slow for a large dataset. Is there any ways to speed up it (e.g. with logical indexing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. For starters, I suggest masking invalid indices with `nan` or `inf` or some special value; using a specific integer is just asking for hard-to-catch issues as you scale the size of your data up. This does give the complication that `b` will need to be of type `float` (so it can store `nan` values) and you'll have to cast it to `long` before using it to index. Personally I think this is worth the indexing safety but you can do as you want.

To use list-style indexing, we'll want to unravel indices into `a` into a 1D tensor for each dimension of `a`.

```
i = torch.arange(n).unsqueeze(1).expand(n,4).reshape(-1)  # something like [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1 ...]
j = torch.arange(4).unsqueeze(0).expand(n,4).reshape(-1)  # something like [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,...]

k = b[i,j].squeeze() # assemble desired indices of c into 1D tensor as well
```

Now `i`,`j`, and `k` each contain `nx4` indices, which is roughly the number of elements you want to replace. Now lets re-index each tensor once to remove all of the invalid indices.

```
valid = torch.where(torch.isnan(k),0,1).nonzero().squeeze().long()
k = k[valid]
i = i[valid]
j = j[valid]
```

And now we're ready to index.

```
a[i,j,:] = c[i,k,:]
```

You may have to do a bit of type-casting to get everything to work out (`a` and `c` for instance need to have the same type.)